# How to count number of lines written for angular 4 in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, lines-of-code

I am writing code in Angular 4 for UI in my project. Is there any automated way to generate the number of lines coded?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "wc -l filename" in command line. I think both Windows and Linux provide this command.